# Calculate number of digits in values

Tags: sql-server

How to calculate number of alphabet in particular values and keep only values where count is 5.
For example - we have two values - qwertyyu and asdfd then i need to keep asdfd in my result and remaining must be null

Comment: are you asking about `LEN`?

Comment: in SQL statement

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the result if you have a value like `123abcde4`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Length of value using LEN and keep or ignore values using a CASE method as shown below-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN LEN(field_name) = 5 THEN field_name 
    ELSE NULL 
END
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the result of only 5 alphabets in the result, try the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(TestVal) = 5 THEN TestVal
            ELSE NULL END As TestVal
FROM TestTable
WHERE TestVal NOT LIKE '%[^a-z]%';
```

Sample data for the execution:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (TestVal VARCHAR (100));
INSERT INTO TestTable (TestVal) VALUES ('qwertyy'), ('abcde'), ('abcd5');
```

This will exclude the `abcd5` from the result, since it contains a numeric.

Please find the [working demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=707d5a9c65da7ebc008a86d5105837db)

Comment: The result will consider only the row has 5 alphabets, it will ignore if all the characters are numbers.

Comment: thanks help me with query to check 5 numbers instead 5 alphabet also

Comment: Use the WHERE clause as `WHERE TestVal NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to check 5 numbers. Please find the [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=823619df79cbe1d62ff4824e75e5189e)

Comment: If the answer helped to solve your problem, you may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Comment: WHEN LEN(TEXT_id) = 5 THEN TEXT_ID  showing error in this line

Comment: Can you please create a db fiddle for the same and share